# Blender Render Animation does not match Viewport Render Animation duration

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, animation, export

I used Viewport Render Animation to see my animation and edit it in premiere pro so that my group could score it (add music). Now that I've finished rendering it, the final Render Animation does not match the Viewport Render Animation's duration. It's shorter.

My settings for the Viewport Render is as shown below:
[image]

As for my settings for the final Render Animation:
[image]

I then imported the image sequence from the Render Animation into premiere pro over the Viewport Render Animation. But the durations do not match:
[image]

The Viewport Render Animation is 00:01:00:00 seconds. 
The Render Animation (image sequence) is 00:00:48:01 seconds.

I've fixed this in premiere pro by stretching it (it looks fine) but I would like to avoid this problem in the future when I make longer animations.
How would I fix this?

(EDIT: Viewport Animation is actually 00:01:00:00 seconds long)